# Google code-prettify Code highlighting not working for Polymer 3

Tags: javascript, polymer-3.x, google-code-prettify

How to use Google code-prettify in Polymer 3?

The syntax highlighting is not working.
Sample code below:

```
class MyView1 extends PolymerElement {
    static get template() {
        return html` 
      <style include="shared-styles">

 </style>

       <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>

                <pre class="prettyprint">
                    <code class="language-java">
                        public static void getValue(){

                            String name = "Vikram";
                        }




                    </code>
                </pre>
```

I have added a working sample at https://stackblitz.com/edit/polymer-element-example-d7n14q where the code can be edited and run as well.

Comment: Is this all your code?  It looks like the tagged template that starts at <tt>html`</tt> is unclosed.

Comment: No this is not the entire code... I shared only a part to give an idea of the problem.

Comment: Please provide example code that parses as JavaScript.  With a partial example, we can't rule out problems like a syntax error that prevents your code from ever running.

Comment: Please see http://sscce.org/ for what we need to help you.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I have added a running sample with editable code at https://stackblitz.com/edit/polymer-element-example-d7n14q Please help.

Comment: Try with https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/google/code-prettify@master/loader/run_prettify.js?autoload=true&amp;skin=sunburst&amp;lang=css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library is working in an old way and doesn't play well with ShadowDom. Instead you should use a library like Highlight.js which is available as a module. In polymer 3 first import the library with your specific language

```
import hljs from 'highlight.js/lib/highlight';
import java from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/java';
hljs.registerLanguage('java', java);
```

then highlight your element with

```
hljs.highlightBlock(this.$.code);
```

here a working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/polymer-element-example-tthbbn

Comment: Thanks a lot... this works. While the code sample is working, when I tried adding this in my actual code, I am getting this error: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: The requested module '../node_modules/highlight.js/lib/highlight.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Comment: Do I need to use WebPack to fix this?

Comment: it depends how you serve files ... you can import the full namespace with import { * as hljs} from 'highlight.js/lib/highlight';

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the style.css of prettify?
https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/prettify.css

Also I would try to put the language class in the pre class attribute.
 (also use lang instead of language)

If it colours it but don't as you expect you could try to send the lang as a get param:
https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js?lang=java

Comment: I have added the running sample at https://stackblitz.com/edit/polymer-element-example-d7n14q Have tried your fixes but it didn't work.  Please review.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got a solution using highlight, but to explain what's happening:

`run_prettify.js` prettifies everything in the DOM at onload time.

It doesn't recurse into shadow DOMs and doesn't prettify content that is added after onload.

You could address both issues by explicitly calling `prettyPrintOne` post render perhaps via `Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender` though I don't know how that interacts with lithtml.

Comment: prettyPrintOne is not defined error... how to define this in polymer?

Comment: It now says "PR.prettyPrintOne is not a function... In WebStorm IDE, PR.prettyPrintOne(escape(this.$.code2), 'java', false); PR is resolved and clicking on it the IDE opens up prettify.js, which has a function $prettyPrintOne(sourceCodeHtml, opt_langExtension, opt_numberLines) {.... but still IDE says prettyPrintOne is unresolved...

Comment: @Vikram Rawat, I think you need to load prettify, not run_prettify.